How many requests per 24 hours a user with "Power Automate Premium" license can do inside Power Platform. confusing numbers
In this official documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations#licensed-user-request-limits. It mentioned that User with "Power Automate Premium" license can do 40K requests per 24 hours, as follow:-

and we have this Service Account with "Power Automate Premium" license: -

But on July I got this email from Microsoft when i was running too many flows for testing things using the service account, and it says that the limit for this service account users is 5,00,000 requests:-

Also when I run the Capacity report inside Power Platform administrator: -

I got these numbers, that the Entitled Quantity is 48,000: -

so, I have those questions, as currently i am totally confused on how those limits work and if i should worry about my service account consumption: -
Question-1) what is the daily request limit for our above service account which have "Power Automate Premium" license? is it 1/2 million requests as per Microsoft email? or is it 40K as per the official documentation? or is it 48K as per the Capacity report?
Question-2) Also in the capacity report, seems the Total Consumed Quantity always exceeds the Entitled Quantity for the service account (the CallerID starts with 3a943******) as per the above picture, But i did not get any email from Microsoft in August, September or in October about exceeding the consumptions nor any flow get affected ...
So can anyone what is going on???
